# How to pass the result of FC command to curl API

Tags: batch-file, curl

May I know how can I pass the result of the FC batch command to a curl API?

Here's my script:

````
@echo off
setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

for /f "delims=" %%i in ('FC /b "C:\MD5Checksum\ChecksumFromActualVM*" "C:\MD5Checksum\ChecksumFromRestoredVMDK*"') do set result=%%i

cd "C:\curl-7.76.1-win64-mingw\bin"
curl.exe curl -X POST "https://api.trello.com/1/cards/BXRp8Bm6/actions/comments?key=xxxx&token=xxxx&text=%result%"```

I assign the value to "result" variable but when it won't post to the trello card
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *`curl.exe curl`*

Calling `curl` once should be enough!

The trailing ```` ``` ```` Markdown code is also a mistake on your end?

There's no need for a variable. In fact, there's no need for a Batch script at all. Straight from the command-line:

```
FOR /F "delims=" %A IN ('FC /B "C:\MD5Checksum\ChecksumFromActualVM*" "C:\MD5Checksum\ChecksumFromRestoredVMDK*"') DO (
  "C:\curl-7.76.1-win64-mingw\bin\curl.exe" -X POST "https://api.trello.com/1/cards/BXRp8Bm6/actions/comments?key=xxxx&token=xxxx&text=%A"
)
```